# is there any way to add Timestamp security header only in WCF?

Tags: wcf, security, binding, interop, timestamp

I'm trying to process a response message form the server which is adding only a timestamp element to the security header. In order to interop I'm creating a WCF service which behaves like the production server, and I want to have such security header only. I was able to configure everything except the Timestamp, it adds a signature including the timestamp element (but I don't want that).

What is the binging configuration that adds only a Timestamp element to the header? Is this possible?

What happens if WCF receives a message with a Security header with a Timestamp element only? It will process such message if the EnableUnsecuredResponse is set to true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is adding a Timestamp  a security feature?

Comment: @Rook the timestamp contains a created and expiry date, and gets a matching signature to prevent these dates being edited. This allows a service to reject a message older than, say, 15 seconds - which prevents replay attacks.

Comment: @Steve Fenton no that makes a 15 second window of replay attacks,  and at a ~100ms latency that is a shitload of requests.

Comment: @Rook If it was the only security measure you were using, it would be a problem. It is one of many, many security measures that you would take advantage of on a standard binding.

Comment: @Steve Fenton huh,  I think I'll stick with TLS and REST

Comment: @Rook I only usually expect time stamps to be used in message level security. This means it is in addition to TLS. Time stamps are more common in SOAP messages. I don't use them except when calling SOAP endpoints. I also prefer unadorned HTTP communication.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure there is such binding. Timestamp is pretty straight forward so I suggest you drop any security configuration and use custom [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to generate the timestamp and push it to the message by yourself.